# Multiple instances of CRON_TZ inside a cron file (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, bash, centos7, cron

Is it possible to have multiple timezones in the `/etc/crontab` file, like below?

```
CRON_TZ=Europe/Paris
*/20  *  *  *  *  root /home/user/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5  *  *  *  *  root /home/user/script1.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And then:

```
CRON_TZ=UTC
*/5  *  *  *  *  root /home/user/watchdog.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10  *  *  *  *  root /home/user/watchdog1.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I've also tried `TZ=Europe/Paris` and `export TZ=Europe/Paris` instead of `CRON_TZ` before each line. But it didn't work like that.

---

I don't want to change the original timezone of the server which is `UTC`. Just want to run certain tasks in different timezones.

---

How can I use multiple timezones like this?

Comment: crond tunes itself by one time zone and calculates specified periods accordingly. you better calculate time shift by one central/specific tz once and add/subtract from all your entries.

Comment: @MTG That doesn't account for daylight savings!

Comment: If your jobs run every hour, then CRON_TZ and daylight saving time are irrelevant. The jobs would run every hour regardless of its setting. Do you want to run the jobs less than hourly, based on a specified time zone, or do you want to run the jobs every hour, with a specific timezone?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The example above is to illustrate how I want it to function. While I have tasks that run hourly, I also have scheduled ones. Like backups etc that rely on a timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put both timezones in `/etc/crontab`, but you can make different files in `/etc/cron.d` each of which has a different `CRON_TZ` and `TZ` setting.

For instance, `/etc/cron.d/chicago`:

```
CRON_TZ=America/Chicago
25 12 * * * root echo Chicago >> /tmp/TZ
```

And `/etc/cron.d/new_york`:

```
CRON_TZ=America/New_York
25 13 * * * root echo New_York >> /tmp/TZ
```

At 17:25 UTC, the content of `/tmp/TZ` is:

```
Chicago
New_York
```

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple timezones in one file?

Comment: Again, no, you need to use multiple files. I think I mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me to have multiple files though.

Comment: @Borsn Then you will have to make having multiple files work for you, or work in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

On a CentOS 7 machine with `cronie-1.4.11-14.el7_2.1.x86_64`, I can have two `CRON_TZ` in one file. My crontab file reads:

```
CRON_TZ=Etc/GMT+0
 * */2 * *  * touch ~/temp/cron-0gmt0evenhour
 * 1-23/2 * *  * touch ~/temp/cron-0gmt1oddhour
CRON_TZ=Etc/GMT+1
 * */2 * *  * touch ~/temp/cron-1gmt0evenhour
 * 1-23/2 * *  * touch ~/temp/cron-1gmt1oddhour
```

`1-23/2` means odd hours. See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204734/9382524) and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/429397/537953).

Result (after it runs for long enough):

```
$ ll ~/temp/ --full-time
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 packard domain_users 0 2020-11-21 22:59:01.108221582 +0000 cron-0gmt0evenhour
-rw-r--r-- 1 packard domain_users 0 2020-11-21 23:25:01.177041834 +0000 cron-0gmt1oddhour
-rw-r--r-- 1 packard domain_users 0 2020-11-21 23:25:01.176041830 +0000 cron-1gmt0evenhour
-rw-r--r-- 1 packard domain_users 0 2020-11-21 22:59:01.108221582 +0000 cron-1gmt1oddhour
```

`CRON_TZ` only controls the timing to start a job, so it is useful only if the job does NOT run on every hour (as Michael pointed out in a comment). Use `TZ` to set the environment variable that the job sees.

Michael's answer (multiple cron files) would not be feasible for non-root users, who [have only one crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/360942/363714). And having multiple `CRON_TZ` is useful to deal with different daylight-saving time in different time-zones.

ps. I got to know my version of cron from the following command inspired by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55683/363714).

```
$ rpm -qf `which crontab`
cronie-1.4.11-14.el7_2.1.x86_64
```

Comment: [A stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47618815/9382524), also using cronie, also manage to change `CRON_TZ` in the middle of a cron file.